# How to set a interval with Puppeteer to run a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, setinterval

I would like to set an interval, so the code updates every second, but only for 2 minutes.

I am not sure how to set this up.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    let game = 'https://lichess.org/hj4DgCNN9BKG';
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(game, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let time = document.querySelector('div[class="time"]').innerText;
        return {                time
        };
    });
        console.log(data);
})();
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is and what you have tried? Are you unsure how to use `setInterval`, or how to make it stop after 2 minutes? This question does not seem to have much to do with Puppeteer

Comment: Actually both. I am quite new with programing so I am not sure how to wrap this function in setInterval so it works...

Comment: `setInterval(() => { /* all your puppeteer code you want to repeat */}, /* time delay in milliseconds, e.g. 1000 */)`. Then use a counter and exit after 120 iterations. Give it a try! See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). You can also do this with a plain old `for` loop and `setTimeout`.

Comment: @RonFutsal your questions will get more attention (and better answers) if you're able to separate your concerns and make each question about one specific thing. I would suggest going with @ggorlen's recommendation, although maybe place your loop inside the Puppeteer `evaluate`, if you can (i.e. if the page is refreshing automatically), as Puppeteer can be quite heavy (and slow) to launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    let game = 'https://lichess.org/hj4DgCNN9BKG';
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(game, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    const end = Date.now() + 120000;

    while (Date.now() < end) {
      let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let time = document.querySelector('div[class="time"]').innerText;
        return { time };
      });
      console.log(data);
      await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
    }
})();
```